# Redirection after login is not working in angular2

Tags: angular2-routing

here I am creating simple login application using Angular2.
I am using template driven form. Manually I am doing authentication for username and password.
But after authentication it is not redirecting to home page.
this is my source code for that,

I have three components

**login component** ,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers:[UserService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  users=[];
  title = 'My Angular2 Login App';
  public msg1:string;
  public uname;
  public psw;

    public user = new User('','');
    public errorMsg = '';
   constructor(private _userService: UserService, private _router: Router){  }

  onClick (value1,value2) {
        this.uname=value1;
    this.psw = value2;
       if(this.uname==="abc" && this.psw===123)
      {
      this._router.navigate(['tutorial']);
    }

  }
```

Here is my **tutorial component**,

```
<p>
  tutorial works!
</p>
<p> {{userName}} </p>
```

this is my app component,

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

this is my **app.module.ts** file

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent,  TutorialComponent, LoginComponent ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, CommonModule ,HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path:'tutorial',component:TutorialComponent},
    {path:'login',component:LoginComponent}
  ])],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Suggest me correct way.

Comment: that is solved?

Comment: Yes i solved this problem.